# Construct std::vector<double> from a double* array of known size

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, initialization

I have a pointer to the first element of a double array: `double* p`.

I also know the length of the array: `n`.

Is there a way I can copy this into a `std::vector`? Preferably using a constructor and allocator. I'd like to do something like

```
std::vector<double> v = std::vector(p, n);
```

but can't figure out which constructor is closest to this. I'm using C++11.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::vector<>` has a constructor that takes a range. You can use it like this:

```c++
std::vector<double> v(p, p + n);
```

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
std::vector<double> v( p, p + n );
```

Or if the vector was already defined then

```
v.assign( p, p + n );
```

If you want to append the vector then

```
v.insert( v.end(), p, p + n );
```